# How to simulate NestJS color logs with Winston logger?

Tags: node.js, winston

I'm trying to make my own Winston logger implementation with similar color pattern to NestJS's ones, but I'm not being successful.

[image: 1]

I'm not able to colorize words in the middle of the log nor to add the ms at the end.
This is my current implementation:

```
format: winston.format.combine(
  winston.format.colorize({ all: true }),
  winston.format.timestamp({ format: 'DD-MM-YYYY, HH:mm:ss' }),
  winston.format.align(),
  winston.format.json(),
  winston.format.errors({ stack: true }),
  winston.format.printf(({ message, timestamp }) => {
    const logTraceId = this.traceId ? `[${this.traceId}]` : '';
    const logContext = this.context ? `[${this.context}]` : '';
    
    return `${timestamp} - ${logContext}${logTraceId} ${message}`;
  }),
  winston.format.ms(),
),
```

I would like to, for instance, make `RoutesResolver` in yellow in the middle of the log. Same for traceId. Also adding the ms at the end of the logs.

Could someone enlighten me here?
Thank you all!

Comment: FWIW, if you simply want to have logs of the same format in your NestJS application, you can use `Logger` class from `@nestjs/common`. I understand that this might be unrelated to your goal.

Comment: @ParzhfromUkraine thanks for the answer, but this is unrelated. I need to enhance my logging functionalities with more detailed info, but want to mimic the way NestJS logs it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this can be achievable by using [Chalk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chalk) or [Ogma Styler](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ogma/styler).
With both, we are able to colorize any string that will be prompted in the console, and here is the result:

[image]